# Georeferencing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am doing georeferencing in QGIS. I have a file saved with the extension .tif. This file shows a map created in epsg: 2175. What should x and y be?
[image]

Comment: This looks like a re-working of the duplicate. Rather than asking it as a new question please revise the duplicate so that it can be reviewed to determine whether it is ready for reopening.

Comment: For the upper right grid intersection you would use X/East:224000 and Y/North:920000. Normally you will want to use 9 pairs to GeoReference a map; 3 on each side and one in the middle. I successfully GeoReferenced your map in QGIS to EPSG:2175 just now by following this Tutorial: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html